# JQGrid edit function using wrong ID

Tags: jquery, mysql, jqgrid

I'm using this model for the jqgrid table:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'clientSide',
                colNames: ["Id", "Id cliente", "RagSociale cliente", "Numero","Anno",
                           "Data di ordine", "Id agente", "Nome agente", "Cognome agente",
                           "Id agenzia", "RagSociale agenzia", "Id utente", "Nome utente", 
                           "Data d'inserimento", "Note", "Disabilitato"],
                colModel: [
                    { name: "id"},
                    { name: "idCliente"},               
                    { name: "ragSocCliente"},
                    { name: "numero"},              
                    { name: "anno"},
                    { name: "dataOrdine"},              
                    { name: "idAgente"},
                    { name: "nomeAgente"},
                    { name: "cognomeAgente"},
                    { name: "idAgenzia"},
                    { name: "ragSocAgenzia"},
                    { name: "idUser"},
                    { name: "nomeUser"},                                            
                    { name: "dataInserimento"},             
                    { name: "note"},                
                    { name: "disabilitato", width:100, sortable: false, resizable:false}
                ],

                sortname: "id",
                sortorder: "asc"
            })
            .navGrid('#pager', {del:false});
```

When I want to edit, I click the record and the edit button, which opens up a new window.

My main problem is that, when I edit, I need the ID that's stored into the id column, instead I get the ID of the row in regards to the table. If my second record has an ID of 53 and I try to edit it, the bindings will be all wrong because instead of passing id=53 it passed id=2 because it's the second record of the table. Any solution to this problem?

----EDIT----

I've added the usage of sessionStorage because of time, but I'd like to know if there's another way of doing it, like using the navgrid edit options

```
colModel: [
                    { name: "id"},
                    { name: "idCliente"},               
                    { name: "ragSocCliente"},
                    { name: "numero"},              
                    { name: "anno"},
                    { name: "dataOrdine"},              
                    { name: "idAgente"},
                    { name: "nomeAgente"},
                    { name: "cognomeAgente"},
                    { name: "idAgenzia"},
                    { name: "ragSocAgenzia"},
                    { name: "idUser"},
                    { name: "nomeUser"},                                            
                    { name: "dataInserimento"},             
                    { name: "note"},                
                    { name: "disabilitato", width:100, sortable: false, resizable:false}
                ],

                sortname: "id",
                sortorder: "asc",
                onSelectRow: function (id) {                    
                    sessionStorage.setItem("idEdit", $("#list").jqGrid('getCell', id, 'id'));

            }
        })
        .navGrid('#pager', {del:false});
```

Just to clarify, pressing edit button opens another page that using a get function and the Id passed, it populates the table in edit, here's the get part of it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        <c:if test="${not empty param.id}"> 
        var parameter = sessionStorage.getItem("idEdit");
        console.log(parameter)
        $.get("get", {
            id: parameter
        }, function(data) {         
            window.data = data;
            ko.applyBindings(window.data);
            $("#scaricata").prop('checked', window.data.scaricata);
            $("#originale").prop('checked', window.data.originale);
            $("#dematerializzazione").prop('checked', window.data.dematerializzazione);

        });         
    </c:if>
```

The if checks if there are parameters. Being an edit, obviously there are.

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use?** Could you include test data for the grid and **how you fill the grid**? The code contains   `datatype: 'clientSide'` which means `datatype: 'local'`, but no `data` parameter and no example of the data. The data which don't correspond the `colModel` or other option is frequently the origin of the problem, which you describe. Moreover no columns have `editable: true` property.

Comment: I'm sure how or where I can see which version I have.
This is the whole code of the grid, I use ajax to fill the table, although I'm not the original writer of this scripts so I don't exactly know how they fill the table

Comment: You can open `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` and to see the version in the comment. The problem that if you say jqGrid proeblem it's the same that you say the problem with your car, but the problem with BMW 7, Porsche 911, Tesla Model S, and Fiat Punto from 1993, VW Bittle 1947 are really different. It the version is not important for you I suggest the to use free jqGrid 4.13.0 from CDN directly (see [URLs](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki)) or download [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/releases).

Comment: Moreover the question about filling the grid, setting of other options especially `editable: true` are important. The test data and the way of filling the grid is really important. Is `id` column is edatable too or the value is just not the same as in your input data?

Comment: Sorry but I'm in kind of a rush, I've tried to use the edit options of the navgrid, but for time constraint, I've resorted to use the sessionStorage to store the ID (value of the column id) of the selected row, so that in the edit page I can use that ID.

I'll edit the code above to show.